# Combine jagged and multidimentional array but with different variable types

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

I'm making a voxel game and now I'm trying to remove the faces that face each other on each voxel. I plan only to do this when loading for the moment. To keep track of this I am currently using arrays with integers. I want to continue using integers for my positions(italic) but not for if a face is disabled or not(bold).

This is how I have configured my array for faces:

> int *[,,]* **[]** blockFaces = new int *[width, height, width]* **[ ]**;

## TLDR;

In short i want to change the array that is bold from holding integers to holding booleans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a tuple for this:

```
(int face, bool enabled)[,,]blockFaces = new(int, bool)[width, height, width];
```